# Why bitcoin change addresses are not just the own address?

Tags: transactions, wallet

Why every wallet generates a new change address instead of sending back to itself?

Answer (score 4):

Privacy.

Reusing one of the addresses an input is consuming from as change would would make it trivial for third party observers to infer which output is change and which is the actual payment.

Furthermore, there is no cost or size benefit to reusing. Bitcoin is UTXO-based, not account based, and there is no fee or complexity difference between using a fresh address vs. reusing an older one.